# Appropriate storage of objects for easy lookup (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, lookup

I have a file with a list of Strings. The input to my program will be new strings and I need a good way to check whenever the input string occurs within my predetermined list of strings (this is a part of a larger program which will make *a lot* of request for whenever certain string are in my predetermined list or not.

Basically I have a set of Strings and I want to check whenever a new String is in that set in O(1) time. What I have used now is to create a `HashMap<String,Boolean>`, and stores all my predetermined strings in that with the Boolean `true` attached. I can then check whenever the string `s` is in my predetermined set by `containsKey(s)`

However, this feels wrong in the sense that a hash map is meant to do more than what I want (pair an input with an output) and here I am only using the `containsKey(String string)` function. Also, I am essentially storing a lot of Boolean which I do not need. But this was the only way I could come up with in O(1) time.

Is there a better way of doing what I want to do?

Cheers

Comment: Does _predetermined_ also mean that it will not change at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a `HashSet<String>`. You can then check it similarly to your `HashMap` with `contains(s)`.

Comment: Thank you, this is very much what I was looking for!